# common roots of bivariate polynomial equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

Let $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$ be bivariate polynomial equations where the polynomials have the same degree, say, $N\geq 3$. Furthermore, both of them have the same terms but different coefficients. For example, $f(x,y) = a_1x^2y^3 + a_2xy^2 + a_3$ and $g(x,y) = b_1x^2y^3 + b_2xy^2 + b_3$. How may common roots of $f(x,y)=0$ and $g(x,y)=0$ are there? I am not interested in finding the common roots but the number. Can Bézout's Theorem help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Bezout's theorem would imply that if $f,g$ had no common factors, then the number of common roots is at most $N^2$.

Comment: And the resultant $R(f,g)$ would decide if $f$ and $g$ had any common roots at all
(in an extension field). Are the polynomials over a field ?

Comment: Hm, what if you compute the Gröbner basis for such varieties?
Do you get anything interesting? (This would be quite nice to experiment with a bit, to get some feeling for the problem).

Comment: That is, the Gröbner basis such that allows lifting, (I never remember which monomial order this is, but it is the default one in Mathematica).

Comment: Since you fix the terms, the Bernstein-Kushnirenko theorem (or Bernstein-Khovanskii-Kushnirenko) would be more precise than Bezout's theorem.

Comment: The Bernstein-Kushnirenko theorem states that the number of common roots of $p_n(x)=c_kz^k, n=1,2\cdots,N$ is N!Vol$(\Delta_1,⋯,\Delta_N)$ I am sorry that I have no sufficient mathematical background and cannot understand the terms involved. Can anyone tell me how is Vol$(\Delta_1,⋯,\Delta_N)$ computed using the coefficients of the polynomials? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think much mathematical background is needed. The $\Delta_i$ is just the convex hull of the set of exponents of the terms involved in the $p_i$, inside $\mathbb{R}^2$, so in your case they are both equal to the triangle with vertices (2,3), (1,2), (0,0). The coefficients don't matter. Vol denotes "mixed volume" but I think that when all $\Delta_i$ are equal, this is just ordinary volume. Have a look at arXiv:0812.4688. BTW, just as Bezout, this only gives an upper bound on the number of solutions, which is the exact number if the coefficients are "general enough".

Comment: To be completely explicit: since the triangle has area 1/2, your equations have at most 2*1/2 = 1 isolated solution. Note that it is possible that you may have no solution at all for some specific coefficients (e.g. x^2y^3 + xy^2 + 1 = 0 and x^2y^3 + 2xy^2 + 2 = 0 have no common root). But what BKK theorem says is that for almost all of the coefficients you will have exactly one root.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

However, I have a question.

The number of roots equals $N!$Vol($\Delta_1,\cdots,\Delta_N$).

Generally, if $N$ increases which means there are more polynomial equations, then the probability of having common roots will decrease.

However, the bound increases with $N$ if we assume the terms of all polynomials are the same, which means $Vol($\Delta_1,\cdots,\Delta_N$) remains unchanged.

Then, there is a contradiction.

Comment: In the BKK theorem, N is also the dimension of the ambient space.

Comment: And, answering the circles case: there are four intersection points, but two of them are complex conjugate. This, however, is basic, more appropriate at math.stackexchange than here.

Comment: Is $N$ the number of polynomial equations, that is, 2 in my case?

Answer (score 2):

I reread the previous posts. The answers are very interesting but the question is really hilarious. When we have the same terms in each equation (with different coefficients in a field $K$) then the problem is essentially a linear one. For instance, here, we obtain (generically) a sole solution in $K$ for $x^2y^3,xy^2$. Then a value for $x^2y^4$, then a value for $y$, then a value for $x$.

The moral of the story is that some trivial matters can lead to exciting discussions and take time before downgrading certain issues to stackexchange !

Comment: The problem is linear only in the sense that finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial of a matrix is linear (that is, not at all).

Comment: Dear Carnahan, I don't understand one word you write. We have a linear system of $2$ equations in the $2$ unknowns $x^uy^v,x^ry^s$. Then we obtain (generically) one solution in $K$ ($x^uy^v=?,x^ry^s=?$). We deduce easily (according to the values of $u,v,r,s$) the solutions in $x,y$, using $p^{th}$ roots. Can you solve a characteristic polynomial with radicals ?

Comment: Moreover, and it is funny, the second part of the calculation is essentially: solving a linear system in $log(x),log(y)$.:)

Comment: Given the statement of the problem, you always get two linear equations.  If there are more terms in the polynomials $f$ and $g$, you will get more unknowns.  Your method only seems to work when you have 2 unknowns.