# About the practice of Bernstein-Kushnirenko theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

The following refers to 
[common roots of bivariate polynomial equations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131479/common-roots-of-bivariate-polynomial-equations) and, in particular to the quim's and auniket's comments.
The BKK theorem (cf.  arXiv:0812.4688. Theorem 5.4) asserts that if we consider $n$ polynomials equations $p_1,\cdots,p_n$ in $n$ unknowns $x_1,\cdots,x_n$, then generically, there are $n!Vol(\Delta_1,\cdots,\Delta_n)$ isolated solutions. Here $\Delta_i$ is the convex hull of the set of exponents of the terms involved in the equation $p_i$. Until this all goes well but $Vol()$ is the mixed volume (cf. arXiv:0812.4688. p.2). My problem is: how can I obtain the exact value of $Vol(\Delta_1,\cdots,\Delta_n)$. With hand ? Or does there exist a software (in Maple or Mathematica) to do that ? I am motivated by this problem on which I break my teeth for some time:

Here $n=4$. Using Grobner theory, I "see" that generically the Hilbert dimension is $0$ and the number of solutions is $12$. The set of exponents in $\mathbb{N}^4$ is as follows

Equ1: (2,0,0,0)(0,1,1,0)(1,0,0,0)(0,0,1,0)(0,1,0,0)(0,0,0,1)(0,0,0,0)

Equ2: (1,1,0,0)(0,1,0,1)(1,0,0,0)(0,0,1,0)(0,1,0,0)(0,0,0,1)

Equ3: (1,0,1,0)(0,0,1,1)(1,0,0,0)(0,0,1,0)(0,1,0,0)(0,0,0,1)

Equ4: (0,1,1,0)(0,0,0,2)(1,0,0,0)(0,0,1,0)(0,1,0,0)(0,0,0,1)(0,0,0,0)

Here $Vol()$ should be $1/2$. Does somebody has an idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gfan is a program designed to do this type of computations (and more). I have no experience with it, but according to the manual (page 529) "gfan_mixedvolume [...] computes the mixed volume of the Newton polytopes of a list of polynomials. The ring is specified on the input. After this follows the list of polynomials." The program and manual are available at http://home.imf.au.dk/jensen/software/gfan/gfan.html

Answer (score 2):

It's more or less easy to do computations in dimensions 2 and 3 by hand. Recall that the mixed volume $Vol$ is just the polarization of the usual volume $V$. In particular, it can be defined as the coefficient in front of $t_1t_2\ldots t_k$ in the polynomial expansion of $Vol(t_1\Delta_1+t_2\Delta_2+\cdots+t_k\Delta_k)$ where "+" stands for the Minkowski sum. Then it's just a question of practice (say, it's a good exercise to do the computations for two segments, a segment and a triangle, etc.). I haven't seen anyone do 4-dimensional computations by hand though.